# Search for book using multiple criteria in java

Tags: java

I have this method which takes n number of arguments and search for a book in an arrayList using couple of arguments. .
How can i make it smaller?
How to sort books by category or author?
thank you in advance.

Here is my method
// search for a book using multiple criteria

```
static void bookSearch(String... varg) { // take varg as parameter
    String title = ""; // place holders
    String author = "";

    if (varg.length > 1) { // check varg length
        title = varg[0]; // if it is greater than 1 initialize needed arguments
        author = varg[1];
    } else {
        title = varg[0]; // else initialize the first argument
    }
    for (Book book : bookList) {

        /*
         * if the title is the same and there is a second argument that
         * match author's name print found it
         */
        if (book.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            if (author.isEmpty() ^ (book.getAuthor().getfName() == author)) {
                System.out.println(" \"" + 
                                   title + 
                                   "\" founded at: " + 
                                   bookList.indexOf(book));
                break;
            }// end of if

        } else if (bookList.indexOf(book) == bookList.size() - 1) {// if not found
            System.out.println("cant find \"" + title);
        }// end of else

    } // end of for loop

} //end of search method
```

Comment: if my answer is useful then dont forgot to accept it.

Comment: With less vertical space, you don't need to comment closing braces. Maybe you need another editor or a different tabwidth.

Answer (score 1):

In `Java8` you can use lambdas and functions to get flexible `filter` book function.

E.g. you have following `Book` class:

```
class Book {
    private String author;
    private String title;
}
```

The `book filter` function could look like this:

```
BiFunction<List<Book>, Predicate<Book>, List<Book>> BOOK_FILTER =
        (books, fields) -> books.stream().filter(fields).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then, all you need is just build required `Predicate` and use this function.

```
public static List<Book> findBookByPredicate(List<Book> books, String author, String title) {
    Predicate<Book> byAuthor = book -> book.getAuthor().equals(author);
    Predicate<Book> byTitle = book -> book.getTitle().equals(title);
    return BOOK_FILTER.apply(books, byAuthor.and(byTitle));
}
```

As you can see, you're not limited only certain number of `Book` fields. You can combine it as you like; `BOOK_FILTER` function stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java 8 lamda expression for this.
Ex.

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("spring", "node", "mkyong");
//Here pass your collection and filter as per your requirement
List<String> result = lines.stream()                 
       .filter(line -> !"mkyong".equals(line))     
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can default `title` to `varg[0]` and set `author` if `varg.length` is greater than one with a ternary. I would prefer a standard loop with a index counter (since otherwise you must search again to determine the index). Next, you need to complete the loop before declaring the title isn't found (I would use a `boolean` to maintain that state). Next, you logically need an or (not a xor) to check that the `author` argument is present and not empty before checking the book author. I would prefer formatted io. Like,

```
static void bookSearch(String... varg) {
    String title = varg[0], author = varg.length > 1 ? varg[1] : "";
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
        Book book = bookList.get(i);
        if (book.getTitle().equals(title) 
                    && (author.isEmpty() || book.getAuthor().getName().equals(author))) {
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" found at: %d%n", title, i);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.printf("cant find \"%s\"%n", title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using lambda expression, other way to make your code a little shorter would be to implement `equals` method for your `Book` class where you can compare two `Book` objects for equality by their title and author. Then instead of:

```
if (book.getTitle().equals(title)) { 
     if (author.isEmpty() ^ (book.getAuthor().getfName() == author)) {

            System.out.println(" \"" + title + "\" founded at: "
                    + bookList.indexOf(book));
            break;
        }// end of if
```

you can just use:

```
Book searchForBook = new Book();
    searchForBook.setAuthor(author); //ins
    searchForBook.setTitle(title);
    for (Book book : bookList) {
        if (book.equals(searchForBook)){
            System.out.println(" \"" + title + "\" found at: "
                    + bookList.indexOf(book));
            break;
        }
```

You can also make the creation of object `searchForBook` one line only, if you add proper constructors in your Book class.

**On sorting** the ArrayList - you can either make `Book` implement `Comparable` and use `Collections.sort(bookList)` or use a `Comparator` instead and use `Comparator` and again use `Collections.sort` before you use the collection, to have it sorted the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be shortened like this:

```
static void bookSearch (String... varg) { 
    String author = "";
    String title = varg[0]; 
    if (varg.length > 1) {                            
        author = varg[1];
    } 
    for (Book book : bookList) { 
        if (book.getTitle().equals (title)) && (author.isEmpty() || (book.getAuthor().getfName() == author)) {
                System.out.println(" \"" + title + "\" founded at: " + bookList.indexOf(book));
                return;
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("cant find \"" + title);
}
```

- Title doesn't need to be in if and else branch. Just initialize on declaration.
- Take the ternary operator from Elliot if you like
- Your outer if only has the inner if (title/author). This can be replaced by &&.
- Just return instead of breaking.
- With the premature return, you don't need else anymore.

A boolean predicate 'matches' which does the same thing in the Book class might be preferred. Sorting can be a good idea, if you don't have to resort by different criteria often and if you search for multiple books - then it can pay off.

A boolean return or a return of the index, where the book was found, might be more flexible. But for reporting the index, I would use a classical for loop, where you get it by the same iteration.

Returning the index would allow to remove the System.outs, so that the caller can decide, how to handle the event: Order a book via net, print to stdout, output with Swing oder JavaFX or whatever.

A pure compareTo would allow efficient search algorithms to find many book in big lists fast and smooth integration in the new Stream collections.

Using varg seems to be a bad idea to me, since it opens the door wide for getting the parameter order wrong.

```
int bookSearch (String title, Optional[String] author) {
```

expresses more clearly what you want - many IDEs support parameter names.